# Make decltype output a non reference type when called with a pointer

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

Is there any way, using `decltype` or any other `c++17` feature, to have the following code snippet

```cpp
T *a = nullptr;
decltype(*a) b = 0;
```

compile to

```cpp
T *a = nullptr;
T b = 0;
```

instead of

```cpp
T *a = nullptr;
T &b = 0;
```

Where `T` is an unknown type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either [`std::remove_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) or [`std::decay`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) like

```
int *a = nullptr;
std::decay_t<decltype(*a)> b = 0;
```

Comment: Does this resolve at compile time or during execution?

Comment: Anything to do with the type system is a compile time process. So this will absolutely happen at compile time.

Comment: @DiegoROJAS Compile time.

Answer (score 2):

One simple way to get this behavior is to decay the l-value `*a` to an r-value with the unary `+` like this:

```
decltype(+*a) b = 0;
```

Note that this will only work for types like `int` where you can use the unary `+`.

Comment: That'll work in this case (which is sufficient for the OP's question), but not in the general case.

Comment: @Eljay That's true. I guess the OP only needs it for `int`, but I've added the caveat anyway, thanks.

Comment: This will not work in my case. I'm using this in the context of a factory where I dont know which type will be supplied (And if it will support the `+` operator). This remains a valid solution for int. Thank you

Comment: @DiegoROJAS These requirements (factory function, where you don't know what type will be supplied, etc) are not at all clear from the question. Could you edit the question to add more details about the context in which you need to use this?

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no way to make `int *a; decltype(*a)` resolve to `int`.

A simple alternative is to  use a type alias rather trying to deal with `decltype`:

```
using T = int;
T *a = nullptr;
T b = 0;
```